# My bank sold my brokerage accounts to another institution. What will happen next tax season?

Tags: united-states, taxes

USAA sold all of its brokerage / IRA accounts to Schwab.  I am not a tax expert, I rely on TurboTax to do things for me.  Entering cost basis, calculating actual gain and loss between two different viewpoints (USAAs and Schwab's) will be a huge pain for me.  Will this all be adjusted automatically (on the tax forms I'll get from USAA and Schwab next year), or should I consider following my plan of selling before the transition, and re-buying right after?

Comment: The mandatory basis reporting by brokers to IRS (and also to you) on 1099-B introduced roughly 2012-5 includes a requirement that it work when transferred from one broker to another, at least if your holdings are newer than that (should say 'covered' on your statements). But for an IRA, basis of individual holdings doesn't matter, only aggregate net contributions.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 meaning for my IRA it doesn't matter anyway, because I wouldn't be putting that info on any tax forms anyway?

Comment: horse: correct. (but no battery staple!)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - you want to make it into an answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't guarantee what will happen but by all logic, Schwab should be responsible for providing proper and accurate tax accounting (1099 and 8949 forms).

Even though TurboTax should be aware of this regime change, I would contact and ask that they provide an update to the program that allows a seamless transition to people in your circumstances.  And if not, there are other tax programs out there  for investors/traders.

It makes no sense to me to sell before the transition and then buy back right after it.  You'll incur needless slippage.  The market risk of being out may work in your favor.  It may not.